# AudioQueueFreeBuffer warning

Tags: iphone, audio, audioqueueservices

I am getting warning "**AudioQueueObject::FreeBuffer: AQBuffer * 0x6273fd0 has enqueue count of 1**" for API AudioQueueFreeBuffer... How to avoid this warning?

I am getting this warning in AudioQueueFreeBuffer API

```
        for (int i = 0; i < kNumberBuffers; ++i) {

            if(mAudioInfo.mBuffers[i] != NULL)
            {
                AudioQueueFreeBuffer(mAudioInfo.mQueue, mAudioInfo.mBuffers[i]);
                mAudioInfo.mBuffers[i] = NULL;
            }   
            XThrowIfError(AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(mAudioInfo.mQueue, mBufferByteSize, &mAudioInfo.mBuffers[i]), "AudioQueueAllocateBuffer failed");

            AQTestBufferCallback (&mAudioInfo, mAudioInfo.mQueue, mAudioInfo.mBuffers[i]);

            if (mAudioInfo.mDone) break;
        }
```

Comment: Post some minimal code that reproduces this error.

Comment: I didn't get answer and also lost 50 points :-(

Answer (score 2):

This occurs when you attempt to call AudioQueueFreeBuffer() on a buffer that has been enqueued in an AudioQueue that is running. You should call AudioQueueStop() on the associated AudioQueue before attempting to free the buffers.

[The doc's for AudioQueueFreeBuffer() say:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioQueueReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005117-CH3-SW16)

> Call this function only if you want to dispose of a particular buffer
>   while continuing to use an audio queue. You can dispose of a buffer
>   only when the audio queue that owns it is stopped (that is, not
>   processing audio data).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++)
{
    AudioQueueFreeBuffer(playState.queue, playState.buffers[i]);
}

AudioQueueDispose(playState.queue, true);
AudioFileClose(playState.audioFile);
```